# Laravel 5.4 Fullcalendar events dont change colors

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I need make somethink like that:
User see many events on calendar. Events got diffrent color depending about their title. Next when user join(save on event) to event this event go to pivot table becouse i make relation and its work good. I need do when user join to event, event will change color for grey.
I make in controller function to checking if event is saving to pivot table. Its working. And in thats same function i make IF for variable $colorrr and it is passing to view. Now make few input hidden fields:

```
@if($colorrr=='grey')
<input type="hidden" value="grey" id="my_color" name="grey" />
@elseif($colorrr=='red')
<input type="hidden" value="red" id="my_color" name="red"/>
@elseif($colorrr=='blue')
<input type="hidden" value="blue" id="my_color" name="blue"/>
@elseif($colorrr=='green')
<input type="hidden" value="green" id="my_color" name="green"/>
@elseif($colorrr=='yellow')
<input type="hidden" value="yellow" id="my_color" name="yellow"/>
@endif
```

Now i need pass this hidden field to JS scipt to option eventColor.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/fullcalendar') }}/fullcalendar.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

                var base_url = '{{ url('/') }}';
                var color = $("#my_color").val();


                $('#bootstrapModalFullCalendar').fullCalendar({
                    weekends: true,
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek'
                    },
                     eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                      $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                      $('#modalBody').html(event.name);
                      $('#eventUrl').attr('href','/home/zapis/'+event.id);
                      $("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('HH:mm '));
                      if (event.end) $("#endTime").html(moment(event.end).format('HH:mm '));
                      else $("#endTime").html('');                      
                      $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                      return false;
                    },

                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    FirstDay: 1,
                    contentheight : 650,
                    editable : true,
                    allDay : false,
                    aspectRatio : 2,
                    slotLabelFormat : 'HH:mm:ss',
                    timeFormat : 'HH:mm',
                    displayEventEnd : true,
                    events: {
                        url: base_url + '/api',
                        error: function() {
                            alert("cannot load json");
                        }
                    },
                     eventColor: color,


                });
            });
        </script>
```

Its only passing one color and i dont know how fix it.
There is my controller:

```
public function index()
{ 
   $eventscolo=DB::table('save_events')->select('events_id')->get();
   $eventsss=DB::table('events')->select('id','title')->get(); 

    foreach ($eventsss as $eventss) 
    {

        if(DB::table('save_events')->where('events_id','=',$eventss->id)->exists())
        {

              $colorrr = 'grey';

        }
        else
            { 
                if ($eventss->title=="Wydzial 1") 
                    {

                       $colorrr = 'red';

                    }
                        elseif($eventss->title == "Wydzial 2")
                        {

                         $colorrr = 'blue';

                        }
                        elseif ($eventss->title == "Wydzial 3") 
                        {

                         $colorrr = 'green';

                        }
                        elseif ($eventss->title == "Wydzial 4") 
                        {

                           $colorrr = 'yellow';

                        }
            } 

    }
  return view('home',['eventscolo'=>$eventscolo,'eventsss'=>$eventsss,'colorrr'=>$colorrr]);
}
```

I hope can someone help me with my problem i dont have any idea to figure it.

Comment: so what is the colour that is being applied to the event?

Comment: Its applied only red i think is sending to view only one color